# SwiftUI - Animation for apps flying in from the side of the screen - iPad Pro

Tags: animation, ipad, swiftui

I think everyone knows the animation of the iOS apps, when you unlock your iPad Pro. The apps are flying sequentially into the screen from the right side I think. Does anybody know how to realize this "flying into the screen" in SwiftUI?

This is my code. I have a DashboardView and the NavigationLinks are my menu buttons. These menu buttons should fly into my Dashboard screen. Currently I have to swipe from left to right for clicking on the buttons because there is a TabView. This TabView is no longer needed:

```
struct DashboardView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var dashboardModel: DashboardModel
    @EnvironmentObject var gameModel: GameModel
    
    @Binding var isConnected: Bool
    
    @State private var index = 0
    @State var currentCarouselIndex = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
         
            ZStack {
                
                LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.black, .gray, .black]), startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing)
                
                VStack {
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    TabView(selection: $index) {
                        
                        NavigationLink(destination: PlayerView()) {
                            
                            CardView(data: dashboardModel.cards[0])
                            
                        }
                        .isDetailLink(false)
                        
                        
                        /*NavigationLink(destination: FastGamedayView()) {
                            
                            CardView(data: dashboardModel.cards[1])
                            
                        }
                        .isDetailLink(false)*/
                        
                        NavigationLink(destination: SaisonsView()) {
                            
                            CardView(data: dashboardModel.cards[2])
                            
                        }
                        .isDetailLink(false)
                        
                        NavigationLink(destination: GamedayView()) {
                            
                            CardView(data: dashboardModel.cards[3])
                            
                        }
                        .isDetailLink(false)
                        
                        
                        NavigationLink(destination: HistoryView()) {
                            
                            CardView(data: dashboardModel.cards[4])
                            
                        }
                        .isDetailLink(false)
                        
                        NavigationLink(destination: StatisticsView()) {
                            
                            CardView(data: dashboardModel.cards[5])
                            
                        }
                        .isDetailLink(false)
                        
                        
                    }
                    .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
                    
                    NavigationLink(destination: EmptyView()) {
                        
                        EmptyView()
                        
                    }
                    
                    
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                }
                
            }
            .navigationTitle("Herzlich Willkommen zur Spielerfassung")
            .toolbar {
                
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                  
                    Button {
                        
                        withAnimation(.spring()){
                            
                            gameModel.currentTeam = nil
                            gameModel.saisons = [Saison]()
                            
                        }
                        
                    } label: {
                        
                        Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
                        
                        
                    }

        
                }
                
                if self.gameModel.offlineChangeCounter > 0 {
                 
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                      
                        Button {
                            
                            if isConnected {
                                
                                self.gameModel.pushOfflineData()
                                self.gameModel.offlineChangeCounter = 0
                                
                            } else {
                                
                                self.gameModel.errorText = "Sorgen Sie für eine aktive Internetverbindung."
                                self.gameModel.showErrorToast = true
                            }
                            
                            
                        } label: {
                            
                            Image(systemName: "icloud.and.arrow.up")
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFit()
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
                            
                        }


            
                    }
                }
                
                if !isConnected {
                 
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                      
                        Image(systemName: "wifi.slash")
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                            .frame(width: 35, height: 35)

            
                    }
                }
                
            }
            .toolbarColorScheme(.dark, for: .navigationBar)
            .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
        .simpleToast(isPresented: $gameModel.showErrorToast, options: SimpleToastOptions(alignment: .bottom, hideAfter: 3, showBackdrop: false, animation: .easeIn, modifierType: .slide)) {
            
            self.gameModel.showErrorToast = false
            self.gameModel.errorText = ""
            
        } content: {
            
            ErrorToastView()
                .padding(.bottom, 0)
            
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide any code?

Comment: I provided the code above. I hope it is helpful.

Comment: Did you try any animations yourself?